# Rails 4 ERB: consistent date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have read several posts such as [How to format time and date from db:datetime record in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249048) and [Custom date time format in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638396) and I feel like I am missing a puzzle piece.

In our project we have setup a conf variable for a date format and we use:

```
my_date_field.strftime(Rails.configuration.date_format_default)
```

Other suggestions are to setup an initializer and use:

```
my_date_field.to_s(format: :date_format_default)
```

Is there any way to make the output of a datetime field default to a format? In our project, unless we specify, we want a date to ALWAYS render the same way and it feels very un-DRY to have to constantly repeat `strftime` or `to_s`, both with their own parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a default format in your translations:

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%a %b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p"
```

Then use the translation helper in your ERb templates:

```
l some_model.created_at
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [I18n (Rails Internationalization)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#how-to-store-your-custom-translations) to set a default date and time format

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
```